# Generalization of Poincaré Inequality

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

**Poincaré Inequality**

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a bounded set, then $\exists c=c(\Omega) \gt 0$ s.t $||u||_{L^2(\Omega)} \le ||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)},   \forall u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$

**We have also a Generalization**

$||u||_{L^2(\Omega)} \le ||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)},   \forall u \in (H^1\bigcap L^2)_{/\mathbb{R}} \equiv H^1_{/\mathbb{R}}$

where $L^2_{/\mathbb{R}}$ $=\{u° \text{s.t }  v \in u° \Rightarrow u=v+c \text{ with } c \in \mathbb{R}\}$

with

$||u°||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}:=$ $\inf ||v||_{L^2(\Omega)}:=$ $\inf ||u+c||_{L^2}$ s.t $v \in u°, c \in \mathbb{R}$

and

$\displaystyle H^1_{/\mathbb{R}}$ $=\Big\{\displaystyle v \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ s.t $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} u\ =0\Big\}$

Can I have a proof for the **Generalization** pls?